# Proper Indexing of Query on Join

Tags: mysql

On this following query statement, I have two questions. First, should this be an inner join instead of a cross join, or is there no performance difference. Second, what should the indexes be to make this go faster? Do I do one index for each of the columns, or a multi-index of all the columns, or both?

```
SELECT     *, 
           a.id  AS auction_id, 
           ab.id AS autobid_id 
FROM       auctions a 
CROSS JOIN autobids ab 
on         ab.auction_id = a.id 
AND        ab.bids > 0 
AND        ab.user_id != a.user_bid_id 
WHERE      a.status = 'active' 
AND        a.end_time BETWEEN $now AND        $future
AND ab.start_price <= (a.bid_count /100)
```

Comment: You have to try because we dont know your table sizes. MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[MySQL](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `ON` clause, you should not use `CROSS JOIN`, that should only be used when you're doing a full cross-product without any relating conditions between the tables; when there are relating conditions you should use inner or outer join. Also, the `ON` clause should only contain conditions relating the two tables (except in outer joins, where conditions on the child table also belong in the `ON` clause). MySQL actually treats `CROSS JOIN` as equivalent to `INNER JOIN`, so it allows what you wrote with no errors, but standard SQL doesn't. Stylistically, when you write `CROSS JOIN` it should be declaring that you're joining without any conditions, so it's confusing to have an `ON` clause.

As for which indexes you need, it really depends on the nature of the data. But the general rule is that only one index per table can be used to optimize a join, so you'll need composite indexes to be able to use it to filter multiple columns. So for your query, you'd probably need at least composite indexes like `(auctions.user_bid_id, auctions.id)` and `(autobids.auction_id, autobids.user_id)`, and possibly also adding in the `auctions.status`, `auctions.end_time`, and/or `autobids.bids` columns. You have to balance the memory overhead of lots of different indexes with the searching benefit they add, and there may be diminishing returns from too many indexes.